# What is the physical significance of the two integration constants that appear in the ladder operator decomposition of the Quantum Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hamiltonian

If I have a simple one dimensional Hamiltonian of the form
\begin{align}
H = V - 
\partial_x^2
\end{align}
and if I know one zero energy state solution $H\psi_0=0$
then I can use the Wronskian to solve for the second solution
\begin{align}
\phi_0 = \psi_0\int 
\dfrac{dx}{\psi_0^2}
\end{align}
then I can construct two ladder operators
\begin{align}
h_{\pm} = 
\left(
\dfrac{a\psi_0'+b\phi_0'}{a\psi_0+b\phi_0}
\pm
\partial_x
\right)
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
H = h_+h_- = 
\dfrac{a\psi_0''+b\phi_0''}{a\psi_0+b\phi_0}
-
\partial_x^2
=
V-\partial_x^2
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are integration constants from solving the zero energy second order differential equation.

What bafles me is the fact their are an infinite number of different ladder operators that combine to form identical Hamiltonians.

What is the physical significance of the two integration constants that appear in the ladder operator decomposition of the Quantum Hamiltonian?